# Search user's tweet with filtered word in python

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to get only filtered tweet but i got this error. How can i solve it? What is the meaning of this error?

```
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = "elonmusk", count = 200000, lang = "en", tweet_mode = "extended")

word="Dogecoin"
for tweet in tweets:
    if word in tweet:
        df = pd.DataFrame([tweet.full_text], columns = ["tweet"])
```

TypeError: argument of type 'Status' is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring here:

```
if word in tweet:
```

Here `tweet` is a `Status` object, so you can't use the `in` operator on it directly. You want to check if a word is in the text of the tweet, so you need to do this:

```
if word in tweet.full_text:
```

Comment: it gives error again. ""AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'text'""

Comment: @yagci My bad, I was looking at an old version of the documentation. It should be `tweet.full_text` **Note:** I didn't get any results when I searched for `"Dogecoin"`, so I changed the search term to `"Starship"`.

Comment: Additional note: The API is not going to let you retrieve 200,000 tweets in one request. Unfortunately, you have to page through old tweets by making multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: argument of type 'Status' is not iterable` means you are trying to loop over something that is not loopable.

This suggests that the return value of `api.user_timeline()` is not a list of tweets (as your code seems to expect), but rather a `Status`-type value.